# CakePHP friendsofcake Search request URI too long

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Based on a suggestion I am attempting to simplify my question. The short question is:

I am using $this->request->query=[] on my Controller to empty the query string regardless of what the user has submitted. If I understand correctly this code is now deprecated as of Cake 3.4 in favor of $this->request->getQuery(). Is there a way to do the same thing using a method that is not deprecated?

Why I am doing it (feel free to judge me harshly):

I have been using the FriendsOfCake Search plugin for CakePHP 3 and loading the results using AJAX. However, after a few searches the calls fail because the Request URI is too long, because they include the _Token value from ever-compounding page loads (which I have tried unsuccessfully to remove).

To solve this problem I was building my own persistent querystring array on the controller and simply resetting to empty with $this->request->query=[]. I see this is now deprecated in the latest versions of CakePHP and I should be using $this->request->getQuery(), however I can't seem to find a way of emptying as I did before. Any suggestions on this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "_ever-compounding page load_"?

Comment: each time the page is reloaded with ajax the token value increases in size, so as more searches are placed the size is "ever-compounding"

Comment: I'd suggest that you elaborate on that a little bit more, ie come up with some more details (version information, code, etc) so that people can reproduce the problem and help you with that. As it stands your question is pretty [**xy-ish**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/227568), ie it's about your attempted workaround, rather than about the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my question.